# Kerberos authentication does not work in Mongodb Enterprise 3.2

Tags: mongodb, authentication, authorization, kerberos, enterprise

Environment Windows 2012 R2. MongoDB Enterprise 3.2.0, this is an evaluation version.

I am logged in as muser1. 
Why it is looking for a field pwd?
How can I fix it?

```
c:\MongoDB\scripts>mongo.exe --authenticationMechanism=GSSAPI --authenticationDatabase='$external' --username muser1@TEST.MNG
MongoDB shell version: 3.2.0
connecting to: test
2016-01-14T14:03:37.572-0800 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: Missing expected field "pwd" :
DB.prototype._authOrThrow@src/mongo/shell/db.js:1395:16
@(auth):6:1
@(auth):1:2

exception: login failed
```

The user exists:

```
MongoDB Enterprise > user = db.system.users.findOne({user: "muser1@TEST.MNG"})

    {
            "_id" : "$external.muser1@TEST.MNG",
            "user" : "muser1@TEST.MNG",
            "db" : "$external",
            "credentials" : {
                    "external" : true
            },
            "roles" : [
                    {
                            "role" : "readWrite",
                            "db" : "test"
                    }
            ]
    }
```

Kerberos is correctly configured based on 3.2 documentation. DNS configured correctly.
MongoDB service is running with a domain account. SPN is there for the default and for the named service also. Tried to have just one of them configured alone then the other one, no luck.

```
c:\MongoDB\scripts>setspn -L m1svr
Registered ServicePrincipalNames for CN=Mongo1,CN=Users,DC=test,DC=mng:
        mongodb/m1.test.mng
        MongoDB_M1_D1/m1.test.mng
```

Here is the startup config file:

```
# Data Node, with minimal oplog and no jurnal
net:
  port: 27017
systemLog:
  verbosity: '0'                    #Debug level from 0-5
  destination: file
  path: C:\MongoDB\logs\m1-d1.log 
  logAppend: false 

storage:
  dbPath: C:\MongoDB\data\m1\D1
  journal:
    enabled: false
  directoryPerDB : true 
  wiredTiger:
    engineConfig:
      cacheSizeGB: 1
      statisticsLogDelaySecs: 1
      journalCompressor: snappy
      directoryForIndexes: true
    collectionConfig:
      blockCompressor: snappy
    indexConfig:
      prefixCompression: true

#replication:
#   oplogSizeMB: 10
#   replSetName: RSTest

security:
  authorization: enabled
#  sasl:
#    hostName: m1.test.mng
#    serviceName: MongoDB_M1_D1
#  keyFile: F:\config\key1.txt
#  clusterAuthMode: keyFile

setParameter:
  authenticationMechanisms: GSSAPI,SCRAM-SHA-1
```

I tried to add a pwd field to the user document (just in case), but no luck.
I am out of ideas.

Comment: did you manage to resolve this issue?

Comment: no, deleted the test VMs, moved to a different NoSQL DB

Comment: It's asking for the pwd field in the shell because you also provided a username. In the case of GSSAPI, you don't need to provide the username or the password... The credentials will come from the owner of the process. In most cases, that is the logged in user.

Answer (score 0):

When using Kerberos Authentication, you need to define the fully qualified domain name for the server you are connecting to as part of the connection string.  Note that the domain portion also needs to be in all caps.  eg:

```
mongo.exe --host servername.TEST.MNG --authenticationMechanism=GSSAPI --authenticationDatabase='$external' --username muser1@TEST.MNG
```